# Can you use LDAP to connect to Active Directory with just an IP, username, and password?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

Is it possible to connect to an AD without knowing the domain or the `CN` `DC` etc?
Given a url like `ldap://1.2.3.4` and a username and password, can a bind attempt be made or must we have the domain or the `CN`/`DN`

Comment: This is usually done in two phases. (1) bind anonymously and search for the DN of the user whose username is X; (ii) try to bind as that DN and password. AD may have some other method.

Comment: Tell us what you have tried and show logs or results and Read:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you [user207421](https://stackoverflow.com/users/207421/user207421) for your suggestion.

I did tested in my system seems it can be possible. please follow the below steps to get it apply.

In the below steps I have shown how I can connect to active directory from another server using AD LDAP with just IP, username, and password

**Prerequisite:**

•   Off the firewall for both of the server which you are going to created.

•   Make sure the both the VM under same VNET and subnet.

**Step 1**: Created a VM e.g. : VM11 and install and Active Directory and DNS server.Set the domain name as contoso.com.

**Step 2**: Created another VM e.g.: VM110

**Step 3**: Join your VM110 to the contoso.com domain.

•   Add the Ip address of VM11 under DNS server in VNET.

[image]

Click over change to set the domain name of your server. I have already setup to contoso.com.

[image]

**Step 4**: installed the Active Directory Lightweight Directory service on VM110 and try to connect to VM11 server for access the Active directory.

[image]

Set up the inbound and outbound port number 389 or 3269 or 636 for the both VM’s. LDAPS communication occurs over port TCP 636. LDAPS communication to a global catalog server occurs over TCP 3269. I am not able to set the port number as I have restriction in my subscription you can try in your system and then try further below steps.

**Step 5:** (1) bind anonymously and search for the DN of the user whose username is X; (ii) try to bind as that DN and password. AD may have some other method.

You can also refer this [document](https://www.sonicwall.com/support/knowledge-base/cannot-connect-to-ldap-server-on-port-389-3268-and-636/170504922409869/) for apply the same.