# I can ping the DC, Domain, IP, but cannot join the domain

Tags: windows, server, dns, active-directory, domaincontroller

So, setting up a brand new domain for the very first time (never set up a brand brand new domain) of Azure boxes (but not AAD - using traditional AD over Azure) trying to get these boxes to communicate has taken me literal days and I am getting very frustrated at these.

DC is VT-EDD-Server
Domain is VT-EDD.local
Client is VT-EDD-IIS1 (I'll have others, but once this is fixed I'll have this solved)

Not sure if I even NEEDED to, but I added the IP for the DC and domain to the client's host file, and now I can ping the server. I have also updated the client's DNS to:

[image]

and when I still try to join the domain I get

```
The following error occurred when DNS was queried for the service location (SRV) resource record used to locate an Active Directory Domain Controller (AD DC) for domain "VTT-EDD.local":

The error was: "DNS name does not exist."
(error code 0x0000232B RCODE_NAME_ERROR)

The query was for the SRV record for _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.VTT-EDD.local

Common causes of this error include the following:

- The DNS SRV records required to locate a AD DC for the domain are not registered in DNS. These records are registered with a DNS server automatically when a AD DC is added to a domain. They are updated by the AD DC at set intervals. This computer is configured to use DNS servers with the following IP addresses:

168.63.129.16

- One or more of the following zones do not include delegation to its child zone:

VTT-EDD.local
local
. (the root zone)
```

I can ping both the DC and the domain by name and IP, but can't join it.

Comment: You can check this [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69667300/can-you-use-ldap-to-connect-to-active-directory-with-just-an-ip-username-and-p/69675831#69675831) which i have answred here which may help you.

Comment: That is not the same issue, Sadly.

Comment: You definitely don't want to be using Google's DNS servers (8.8.8.8). They're not going to resolve your domain.

Comment: So just let it auto resolve?

Comment: Most probably, your DC is also a DNS server. In this case, put the DC's IP address as preferred DNS for the client you want to join. If not, put the IP address of one of your domain's DNS server. By doing so, you don't need to add anything in your client host file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After creating a ADDC in azure, joining the server to it, and adding the DC's IP to the DNS in Azure, I was able to complete the process.