# How to add computer to domains with Active Directory

Tags: active-directory

I have been assigned a task to create AD and join computers with them, i have created a virtual machine with windows 2019 server, and also setup the domain but facing issues in joining computers to that, any help is appreciated...[image]

Comment: The error message seems self-explanatory. What do you need help with?

Answer (score 0):

This is usually done in two phases. (1) bind anonymously and search for the DN of the user whose username is X; (ii) try to bind as that DN and password. AD may have some other method.

You might also missed to add the IP address of your domain controller into DNS server in VNET.

> Note : Both the VM (Domain Controller) under same VNET and subnet and
> Off the firewall for both of the server as well.

You can refer this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69667300/can-you-use-ldap-to-connect-to-active-directory-with-just-an-ip-username-and-p/69675831#69675831) which i have answered long back regarding the same how we can add a domain controller to a domain without missing any steps.